# How can I enable a user to renew a membership that has been cancelled?

Tags: civimember

Here's what has happened so far: Membership fees increased at the beginning of the year. A user was able to renew prior to the increase being implemented in CiviCRM. The situation has been explained to the user, the payment refunded and the membership status set to cancelled.

When the user goes to the membership renewal page they see a message saying that as the membership has been cancelled it can't be renewed. I don't want to delete the membership because that would also delete the contribution record, so I'd lose the record of the fact that a payment was made and refunded.

What is the best practice approach in this situation?

Comment: Can you set it to 'override = Grace' then let them renew, then clean up by removing the override status?

Comment: Thanks Pete. I can, but it's a bit of fudge, don't you think?

Comment: I think the fact that a Cancelled membership prevents onward memberships is an issue and I have raised on SE if not on JIRA but not going searching for it just now.

Comment: So why do i then go off and search! Here is one. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19264

Comment: Even found the one I meant https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18177

Answer (score 1):

One fudgy option would be to set it to 'override = Grace' then let them renew, then clean up by removing the override status

The fact that a Cancelled membership causes problems for people trying to then renew/complete have been raised in JIRA. See [this](http://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19264) and [this](http://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18177)